# git rebase between merges results in conflicts in completely unrelated files

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a large Git repository where a bug has been introduced some months ago
and I’d like to `bisect` it, by first introducing a commit back in the past of
the repository and then replaying the merges (doing `rebase` onto the new
commit), as indicated in the diagram below.

I understand that due to the merges, Git does not seem to work as well as
expected, but I’d like to have a better idea why that happens (and if there are
parameters which could help it work better).

- The file modified in `patch` is never modified again by any commit in `master`
- I tried `rebase` with and without `--preserve-merges`, and both failed at some
  merge not far from the commit `patch`
- The differences shown in the conflicts make no sense, e.g. some whitespace in
  a file, unrelated lines in another... is there any useful information I could
  try to extract from them, or is it simply garbage and I should not spend any
  time trying to understand it?
- Is there a different parameter/merge strategy that could help advancing the
  merges?

Note: in the end, my combination of `git apply; git bisect` did work, but I’m
still interested in alternative solutions or explanations about Git’s behavior.

> [image: Summary of my issues with git-rebase]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic problem is simple to describe but hard to solve.

You're at the tip of `master`.  Those commit graphs are nice, but hard to type in :-) so let's use a very simplified ASCII one here.  (This is just a restatement of the problem, simplified and with different labels.)

```
                D
              /   \
A - B ----- C       F - G   <-- master
              \   /
                E
```

Here, a bug is introduced at commit `B` and hence present in every child commit (`C` through `G`).  To put in a fix, we want to create a new sequence of commits (I'll use lowercase letters rather than `C'`, `D'`, etc) with the fix `x` installed as a new commit:

```
                d
              /   \
A - B - x - c       f - g   <-- [anonymous; will become master]
              \   /
                e
```

In order to do this, git (`git rebase -p` in this case—note that a *typical* rebase *removes* merge commits!) must make new commits based upon the existing commits.  For non-merges like new commit `c`, this is not too tricky: rebase gets a diff of `C` vs `B` and then applies that patch to the source tree attached to commit `x`.  That is, rebase does `git cherry-pick master~3` while on the new anonymous branch.  No problem so far!  Now rebase needs to create commit `d`, which is also not a problem, it just needs to do `git cherry-pick master~2`, which it does, giving:

```
                d
              /
A - B - x - c
```

Making `e` is a bit trickier because its parent commit should be `c`.  In principle, rebase leaves `d` hanging, rewinds to `c`, and does `git cherry-pick master~1^2` to copy `E`.  (I think the rebase script actually does its own `git commit-tree` operations so that it doesn't have to rewind the anonymous branch, but this works out the same, it just involves some internal hairiness here.)  This gives us:

```
                d
              /
A - B - x - c
              \
                e
```

This is where we hit a problem: how will rebase create a merge commit `f`?  It can't compare the tree for commit `F` against that for `D`: that's just one half of the merge.  It can't compare `F` against `E` either: that's just the other half of the merge.  So it can't use `git cherry-pick` as this requires picking one side or the other of the original merge.

The solution rebase uses is to run `git merge` (or rather the internal bits that `git merge` runs).  This way any changes introduced by `x` that continue through the new `d` and `e` are handled correctly as well.

(This does introduce an entirely different problem: if `F` is an "evil merge", i.e., a merge that changes things not changed in either parent, the reproduced tree for merge `f` won't match up with the tree for `F`, as git will never see the "evil merge" changes.  What's needed is a variant of `cherry-pick` that can compare the merge commit's tree against all its parents—as a combined diff of sorts, except more complete than git's standard combined diff—and apply that diff to all the input trees.  But there's no such octopodal-cherry-pick [`git calamari-pick`?], so it's just not available.)

---

Anyway, this kind of rebase uses merge, and here you're seeing the same merge conflict that, presumably, occurred during the original merge.  If you simply solve it again the same way—using `git rerere` for instance—that would allow you to proceed.  Unfortunately, there's no way to retroactively turn on `git rerere` (even though I think it's easy enough to *write* such a thing).

Comment: Nice answer, and casts some light on an issue I'm having, too. I really wish there were some "damn the torpedoes" option for rebase that would *not* use the merge machinery, and instead just blindly copy the state of the repo for merge commits (for `f` in this example). I'm trying to rebase a complex history onto a new repo with an empty initial commit, and git just seems unable to do this without me re-enacting each merge resolution. rerere doesn't help, since it's unrelated history.

Comment: @jwd: note that normal rebase (the one without `--preserve-merges`) just discards merge commits entirely. It's interactive rebase with `-p` that re-creates them. To copy committed source trees directly, rather than turning normal (non-merge) commits into change-sets that are re-applied, consider using `git filter-branch`.

Comment: thanks for the extra info. In my case, I *did* want to preserve merges (since parts of the complex history I was transferring had merges). I also wanted to put all my changes on top of a base commit in another repo, which I had no control over — hence the rebase. No great solution was found, alas.